# K(A,B) is closed and bounded

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I found this proposition in a article but the proof is not in it. Let be $(X, ||\cdot||)$ a Banach Space, if $A \subset X$ is compact and $B$ is bounded and closed then:
\begin{equation}
K(A,B):= \{ta + (1 - t)b: t \in [0,1], b \in B, a \in A\}\hspace{.1cm}\text{is closed and bounded}
\end{equation}
The fact that $K(A,B)$ is bounded is very easy to prove. How to prove that $K(A,B)$ is closed?

Comment: You might try showing its complement is open.  Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly the case if $B=\emptyset$.

If $B\ne \emptyset$, then consider a sequence $t_na_n+(1-t_n)b_n\to x$, for some $x\in X$. By compactness of $A\times [0,1]$ there is an increasing sequence $n_k\nearrow\infty$ such that $a_{n_k}\to a\in A$ and $t_{n_k}\to t\in [0,1]$. Now, two cases:

- if $t\ne 1$, then $b_n=\frac{x-t_{n_k}a_{n_k}}{1-t_n}\to \frac{x-ta}{1-t}=b$ and $b\in B$ since $B$ is closed and $b_n\in B$ for all $B$. Hence, $x=ta+(1-t)b$ with $b\in B$, $a\in A$ and $t\in [0,1]$.
- if $t=1$, then \begin{align}\lVert t_{n_k}a_{n_k}-x\rVert&\le\lVert t_{n_k}a_{n_k}+(1-t_{n_k})b_{n_k}-x\rVert+\lVert -(1-t_{n_k})b_{n_k}\rVert\le\\&\le \lVert t_{n_k}a_{n_k}+(1-t_{n_k})b_{n_k}-x\rVert+\lvert 1-t_{n_k}\rvert\sup_{b\in B}\lVert b\rVert\to 0\end{align}
  And therefore, $x=\lim_{k\to\infty} t_{n_k}a_{n_k}=1\cdot a=1\cdot a+(1-1)b$ for any $b\in B$.